# Is there a way to retrieve all the DataGridView data (rows/columns) from an external program/process?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have searched the Internet far an wide on how to do this and have found nothing on this subject.
Is this even possible? I can get the `hwnd` by using `EnumChildWindows` but I'm stuck as to where I go from there because I can't find the Const values for a DataGridView anywhere.

If this is possible could someone please post an example on how to do it?

Comment: Check out this [link](https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/asmabegam/external-program-text-read-using-VB-Net/&hl=en-NG)

Comment: I have actually went through that article before but it doesn't pertain to the DataGridView, that only retrieves text from a control like (textbox,label,ect…). That won't pull the data from the DGV.

Comment: You can get all the Rows values from a DataGridView (or any other `Table` type control) using UI Automation. Do you know how to get the handle of the Window (a Form, here) that contains the DataGridView?

Comment: Yeah getting the handle isn't a problem. Unfortunately I need to use API and not UI Automation, although I wish I could.